# ajax jquery getJSON- request url

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use getJSON to display data in my webapp.

Than I need to download the same data as CSV.

Unfortunately, IE doesn't support the a.download attr.

So I need to make another call to the SRV with the same parameters.

The easiest way would be to get the request GET url from the getJSON and call it again (with format=csv)

But how do I get the request URL?

Comment: What is the reason behind downloading same data as CSV again ?

Comment: [JSON to CSV conversion example](http://jsfiddle.net/sturtevant/vUnF9/).

Comment: mccannf - 10x, but not relevant - I need to download the CSV

Comment: Shanoop - The app display the data, then the user can also download it, this is the app requirment

Comment: I did the following work around- I save the JSON result, and than when the user click the download, I send the JSON result back to the srv to a script that transform it to CSV that is then downloadd - thanks to IE for waisting our time and bandwidth.